# Xamarin item click on card in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I made a Recycler and Card view that show me photos

For exemple (without the text below):

[image]

I have more details on every photo, like: location, name etc..

Now, i want to click on photo and instead of the photo, i will see the details of the photo that i click on.

This is my code:

```
class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView ImageView { get; set; }

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
    {
        ImageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
    }
}
class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<PetEntity> _lstData;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<PetEntity> lstData)
    {
        _lstData = lstData;

    }

    public override int ItemCount => _lstData.Count;

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;

        var image = ImageHelper
            .GetImageBitmapFromUrl(_lstData[position].PictureURL);

        if (image == null)
            viewHolder.ImageView.SetImageBitmap(
                ImageHelper.GetImageBitmapFromUrl(
                    StaticConst.Uri + "Content/NA.png"
                    ));
        else
            viewHolder.ImageView.SetImageBitmap(image);

    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
            Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewHolder vm = new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        return vm;
    }
}
```

I tried some things but without success so I did not add to my code here.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.Click` method to  the required view element.
Also it must be done in  OnCreateViewHolder method:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

It will be something like this:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
   {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
            Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewHolder vm = new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
       vm.ImageView.Click += delegate 
    {

    //Your code here 

    };
        return vm;
  }
```